# why go routine only operate on one core

Tags: go

I tried to apply the future pattern of go from 
http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/futures

But I found that the go routines only execute on one cpu core. I'm sure that I set all the environment variables correctly like the number of cores. And I'm also sure my go routine will take lots of time. Here's how I did it.

```
Batch := make(chan *NNBatch, BatchNumber)
for i := 0; i < BatchNumber; i++ {
        go func(Index int) {
            Batch <- Self.TrainBatch(TrainData, LableData, Config, RandomTable[Index])
        }(i)
    }
for i := 0; i < BatchNumber; i++ {
        Delta := <-Batch
.....
```

It's trying to calculate the back propagation error and each layer is over 100 nodes so it should take lots of time.

Is there anything I did wrong? The cpu usage is fixed at 25%

Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Could you post some profile data: http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: I made a sample program like this one which was successfully using all the cores (provided that I set the GOMAXPROCS variable correctly).To be sure that the number of cores is properly set, use the runtime.GOMAXPROCS method at the beginning of your program.
Another possibility is that Self.TrainBatch is blocking for some reason.